# input field setter function doesn't work after manually changing value

Tags: javascript, php, html

I need help understanding this behaviour on my php page.
I have a table with data fetched from a mysql database, and each row of this table has a button like this:

```
<button onclick='fillform(arg1, arg2, arg3)'>+</button>
```

which is invoking the following js function:

```
function fillform(arg1, arg2, arg3){
 document.getElementById('input1').value = arg1;
 document.getElementById('input2').value = arg2;
 document.getElementById('input3').value = arg3;
}
```

So everytime I press the button on that specific row, the data form that row are set as value of 3 input fields on the same page.

Everything works fine, but if I manually change the value of one of the inputs, when I press the button again from any row, that specific input field is not updated anymore from the fillform() function and is stuck with the value I typed.

the input fields don't have any other attributes set beside id, so they are like this:

```
<input type="text" id="input1">
```

Is there a way to make the function have precedence or am I missing something in the code?
Thanks

Comment: `getElementById` is a function. You need to call it with parentheses instead of brackets: `document.getElementById('input1')`.

Comment: thanks, I mistakenly put brackets in here but I have parentheses on my code, sorry!

Comment: In your first code block, where are arg1, arg2, arg3 defined? Are those placeholders for the values of a single row? Are you getting any error in the browser's console at any point?

Comment: Also, make sure you open a javascript error console in your browser. (ctrl-shift-i on firefox)

Comment: they are the DB data fetched from a query, so they are defined as $row['field1'] which I put as arguments to the function, along with " " since they are all strings. I don't get any error and the function works normally until I type something in one of the input fields.

Comment: I would make sure `fillform` is being called again. You can put `console.log(arg1, arg2, arg3)` inside that function to see if it's called again and to see if your arguments are passing the correct values.

Comment: @JM-AGMS so the function is called again correctly every time I press the button, the arguments are passed and I can see them all in the console. When I type something in one of the input, it stops getting updated even though the other ones do but I still see the arguments being passed.

Comment: @Cartwright92 Then there is some other code or browser extension interfering. Here is your code working perfectly: https://jsfiddle.net/eq8hgm0L/

Comment: ok now I don't know what happened but I tried changing the `.value` into `.setAttribute(value, arg1)` and nothing changed. I revert back to `.value` and now everything works as it should... I'm speechless.

Comment: Sometimes web dev is just magic and you have to accept that fact.